# JavaFX CSS center alignment

Tags: css, javafx-8

I am making a custom theme in JavaFX using CSS and I am trying to make all HBoxes and VBoxes have a center alignment. I have looked everywhere to find if there is a styling class for parents or HBoxes but I can't seem to find one. I know that I could just do `HBox.setAligent(Pos.CENTER);` but I do not want to type that command for every HBox or VBox I have. What can I do to make all HBoxes have center alignment without having to use custom classes and putting it in a CSS file?

Comment: If you want help with some facet of your code, you'll need to include that code in the question.

Comment: @TylerH While I agree many questions benefit from code examples, in this case the question seems pretty clearly stated even without it. To paraphrase "Does `HBox` (and `VBox`) have a default style class, and if not is there a way to provide styles to all `HBox`es (or `VBox`es) without one?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#hbox), the style class for `HBox` (and `VBox`, and also any node that is not a `Control` subclass) is empty by default.

You can however use a [Type Selector](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#introscenegraph). Quoting the documentation:

> Node's getTypeSelector method returns a String which is analogous to a CSS Type Selector. By default, this method returns the simple name of the class.

So you just need the class name as the selector. SSCCE:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class AlignmentTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        ListView<String> listView = new ListView<>();
        TextField textField = new TextField();
        Button button = new Button("Click here");
        Label label = new Label("A label");

        VBox root = new VBox(5, new HBox(5, listView, button), new HBox(5, label, textField));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("alignment-test.css");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

with alignment-test.css:

```
HBox, VBox {
    -fx-alignment: center ;
    -fx-padding: 10 ;
}
```

[image]